# laravel @lang key from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have language file ex: lookup.php for each respective locale, with input

```
'STATUS.Active' => 'Active'
```

in blade templating how to, after retrieving data, let say the key that i get is only 'STATUS.Active'. How to use it inside @lang ?

```
@lang('lookup.' + $data->status)
```

is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate strings in PHP :

```
@lang('lookup.' . $data->status)
```